# Gmail doesn't show mail when opened from notification bar

Tags: gmail

When I get a new mail on my Gmail and it appears on then notification bar and I click on it, the Gmail app starts and show the following only:

[image: Gmail screenshot]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

I waited for **9 hours**, nothing changed.

For a test, I clicked on a random white area and the Reply function was activated!

So it seems, the mail was long open but the progressbar never disappears. If I press Back and open it inside the app, it shows the letter with no problem.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

This [appears](https://plus.google.com/+ArtemRussakovskii/posts/M7aqnyjgEC1) to be a bug in the GMail app. I have seen this myself a few times and normally clicking the '<' arrow in the top left and opening the email again sorts it. Other times I have to kill the app and re-launch it.

Comment: Does Google know this? How can an application that used by millions contain a bug that prevents normal usage?